# iterating on all files of a directory from neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I access the filesystem from a Neo4j script?
I need to call apoc.load.json on all the files contained in a directory ...

so the pseudo code should be

```
get list of files in  directory
UNWIND list of files AS filename
call apoc.json.load (filename) YIELD value
WITH value
blah blah
RETURN
```

Comment: Would it work to get the list of filenames using your favorite scripting language and then pass the list as a parameter to Cypher?

Comment: Yes via piping it may work but the point is that I have to make a script that will run on the browser :/
Right now i am extending the apoc library to do it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now (at least since neo4j 4.1) an [apoc.load.directory](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/overview/apoc.load/apoc.load.directory/) function that can return all the file names that conform to a pattern under a directory. In neo4j 5.x, it is found in the [extended apoc](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/) plugin.

For example, to get all the `.json` files directly under the configured `import` directory (read the docs to understand how directories are handled):

```
CALL apoc.load.directory('*.json', '', {recursive: false}) YIELD value AS filepaths
UNWIND filepaths AS filepath
CALL apoc.json.load (filepath) YIELD value AS row
// Process each row
...
RETURN
```